# Symlink(): Operation not permitted

Tags: php, laravel, centos

I'm running on a Centos Webpanel (CWP), I'm currently logged in as a root, and I was trying to run a php artisan storage:link command, but it doesn't seem to work, and it throws me an error that says:

```
In Filesystems.php line 340:
Symlink(): Operation not permitted
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

I've tried running this command

```
sudo chown -R myusername:myusername storage
```

And this

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /path/to/parent/directory`
```

I'm trying to run a simple command to deploy my project. But I got stuck here on this issue.

Comment: What user are you running the command `php artisan storage:link` with?